# Is the function a linear operator? $D(f)= 2(d/dx)f - 3f$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P^2$ be the set of polynomials with degree $2$ or less. Is the function $*D(f)= 2(d/dx)f - 3f*$    a linear operator? Explain

So what Ive been thinking is to test the two properties of additivity and multiplication. However I have **trouble understanding how to check the properties.**

$L(u+v) = L(u) + L(v)$

$L(c*u)= c*L(u)$

I picked a random polynomial of $2x $so$ D(2x)4

$D(2x) = 2(2x)' - 3(2x)  = 4-6x$

Now the **trouble is with checking the properties.**

my attempt -->

$D(u+v) = 2(d/dx)f(u+v) - 2f(u+v) ....$then I would distribute but it doesn't look like it will end up looking like $D(u+v)??$

Help

Comment: If you pick 2x it's not random. However, you should choose an **arbitrary** polynomial $f$. Just call it $f$. In order to verify multiplicativity, also choose a number $c$. Use the symbols - not specific numbers or polynomials. Then prove that $D(cf) = c\cdot D(f)$. Note that $D(f) = 2f'-3f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$D(u+v)=2\frac{d}{dx}(u+v)-3(u+v)=2\frac{du}{dx}-3u+2\frac{dv}{dx}-3v.$$ Also $D(u)+D(v)$ is equal to the same thing. Similarly check the second property.

More generally you can prove that $a_0\frac{d^n}{dx^n}+a_1\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}+\dots+a_{n-1}\frac{d}{dx}+a_n$ is also a linear transformation.

Comment: Thanks @Shahab , for the multiplicative property   I got                                             D(c*u) = 2(d/dx)(c*u) - 3(c*u)............................ c*D(u) = 2c(d/dx)(u) -3c(u)...Would these not be equal since the derivative of (c*u) is different from the derivative of (u)??

Comment: @kal: These will be equal since the constants may be "pulled out" of the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

> D(u+v) = 2(d/dx)f(u+v) - 2f(u+v) ....then I would distribute but it doesn't look like it will end up looking like D(u+v)??

Because $f$ is the argument of the operator not part of it.   When you alpha-substitute $u+v$ for the variable $f$ there should not be any $f$ remaining in the expression.

$$\begin{align}
D(f) ~ = & ~ 2\tfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}(f)-3(f) \\[2ex] D(u+v) = & ~ 2\tfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}(u+v)-3(u+v) \\[2ex] \vdots \\[2ex] = & ~ D(u)+D(v)\end{align}$$

Can you fill in the middle?

Comment: I think you need to replace $3$ by $-3$.

Comment: Details.  ... but thank you. @Shahab.